# Melhores práticas para envios de emails e evitar spam

Tags: php, envio-de-email, email, phpmailer

Nos dias atuais, quase todo web site ou sistema web quase inevitavelmente necessitam de funcionalidades com envio de e-mails, seja em formulários de contatos, recuperação de senha, ativação de conta, confirmação de pedidos e etc.

Quais as melhores práticas para evitar que esses e-mails sejam pontuados como *spam*?

- Qual formatação correta do cabeçalho do email `$headers .= "Content-type:text/html...` ?
- É permitido o uso de CSS para estilizar?
- É permitido o uso de imagem, qual a melhor maneira de usar?
- Existe um limite de destinatários?
- É melhor usar a função [mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php), ou uma classe como [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) para envio de e-mail autenticado?

Em resumo, quais as principais regras *anti-spam* para evitar que os e-mails sejam pontuados como *spam*?

Comment: http://www.antispam.br/boaspraticas/

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Acho que não é bem isso que ele quer saber.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge na verdade isso responde apenas algumas das diversas questões, mais mesmo assim obrigado.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ele quer melhores práticas e aí está uma quantidade delas. Além disso, eu postei o link como comentário porque não vou ter tempo pra dar uma resposta consistente, e pra somar conteúdo ao tópico, deixei o link para que ele tivesse algo a mais para se basear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

O conteúdo do e-mail é apenas um ingrediente entre "melhores práticas para envio de e-mails".

Há muitos outros fatores que influenciam a classificação como *spam* ou não.

#### Reputação do endereço IP

Primeiramente, o próprio endereço IP. Por exemplo: se o seu IP estiver numa faixa de baixa reputação, isto por si só pode ser motivo de rejeição do e-mail, independente de tudo o mais. Eu já tive essa experiência: contratei um provedor de VPS bem barato, e descobri que qualquer e-mail enviado a partir de seus servidores são automaticamente rejeitados pelo *Yahoo! Mail*. Em suma: a **reputação do endereço IP** é um fator importante. Provedores sérios, profissionais e modernos, com forte política de anti-spam, terão boa reputação e isto não se torna um problema.

#### Registros DNS

Outro fator técnico importante está relacionado aos **registros DNS**. Idealmente, o endereço IP sendo utilizado para os envios deve estar firmemente associado ao domínio do endereço remetente, inclusive com **DNS reverso** apropriadamente configurado. Além disso, registros **SPF** e **Sender ID**, bem como assinaturas **DKIM** e **DomainKeys** em todos os e-mails enviados, são ótimas medidas para evitar a caixa de spam e cultivar uma alta reputação como remetente. A cada sistema que eu preparo para uma aplicação, faço todo esse trabalho envolvendo os registros DNS e as assinaturas mencionadas, e o resultado costuma ser "**Inbox**", ou seja, nada de caixa de *spam*.

#### Uso ético

Também muito importante é **como** seu servidor/aplicação irá fazer os envios. Comprou uma lista com milhões de e-mails e enviou o mesmo anúncio para todo mundo? A reputação irá despencar e os envios serão classificados como *spam*. Por outro lado, se seu sistema se **comportar bem**, enviando e-mails apenas para aqueles que legitimamente interagirem com o seu sistema, com "***double opt-in***" (ou seja, confirmação/verificação de e-mail através do envio de um *link*), e seguindo demais regras de "comportamento" ético, sem envios indevidos, você está cultivando uma reputação excelente. A manutenção do cadastro de e-mails é outra tarefa importante: envio de e-mails para endereços inexistentes, por exemplo, inevitavelmente acontece com o tempo, e é importante acompanhar os *bounces* (retornos), mantendo a base de cadastro de e-mails sempre a mais limpa possível.

O número de destinatários pode ser enorme, desde que sua "lista" tenha sido construída com o tempo e seja "verdadeira". Enviar um monte de e-mails de repente para um monte de endereços... **é spam**.

Ao migrar uma base de usuários de porte médio ou grande, de um provedor para o outro, é preciso certificar-se com o provedor as regras de uso de envio de e-mails. Eu já negociei com mais de um provedor e nosso servidor foi colocado na lista branca, pelo fato de seguirmos as melhores práticas no envio (no caso, envio de mensagens espirituais diárias para cerca de 6000 endereços - todos cadastrados por vontade própria, com double opt-in, etc). Geralmente os provedores têm um mecanismo de controle/filtragem/limite, mas que pode ser desativado sob requisição, viabilizando envio em maior quantidade.

#### Cuidados Técnicos

Seguindo as orientações acima e mais alguns cuidados técnicos no envio das mensagens (Return-Path correto e válido, endereço do remetente correto e válido, diálogo do protocolo SMTP correto), torna-se ***quase*** irrelevante o **conteúdo** do e-mail, caso o seu e-mail seja realmente honesto e apropriado... em outras palavras: caso o seu e-mail ***realmente não seja spam***, então é muito difícil que seja classificado como spam *devido ao **conteúdo***. (Dito isto, é claro que há várias dicas que se resumem a nada mais que "bom-senso", evitando linguajar excessivamente "promocional", ou palavras obscenas, etc.)

#### Compatibilidade entre leitores

As suas perguntas pontuais, exceto sobre quantidade de destinatários, que já vimos, são sobre: content-type, CSS, imagens, e mail() x PHPMailer.

São perguntas pertinentes e importantes, mas muito pouco relevantes para a pontuação como SPAM ou não. Na verdade, um e-mail que é apenas HTML com uma imagem, sem texto nenhum, pode ser considerado suspeito. Fora isso, a resposta é "tanto faz", considerando a questão de pontuação como spam.

Essas perguntas são importantes sim para construir e-mails que sejam corretamente apresentados no maior número de ambientes possível: Outlook, Thuderbird, Gmail, Yahoo, e demais leitores de e-mail, que são muitos. Aí sim estas respostas precisam ser buscadas e as melhores práticas devem ser seguidas.

As melhores práticas de **HTML para e-mail** são bem diferentes daquelas para sites na web. Na verdade, chegam até a ser opostas. E dependem muito do que você quer. Para e-mails transacionais simples, às vezes é preferível não usar HTML, e ficar com Texto simples. Você pode também se basear no modelo dos grandes sites, como Twitter, Facebook, Google, etc. - no que se refere ao HTML.

O CSS deve ser inline (atributo `style`). Em geral, o uso de imagem deve ser restrito à decoração, e não ser o principal. Mas depende: se seu mailing é catálogo de produtos, pode ser importante ter as imagens dos produtos.

A função mail() pode ser usada, mas bibliotecas como PHPMailer ou outras facilitam bastante a codificação e são uma boa opção. Penso que o mais importante é a estrutura "por trás"... eu costumo instalar e configurar o Postfix para fazer os envios...

***E-mail Deliverability*** é um tópico amplo e extenso... espero ter ajudado um pouco.

Comment: Amplo, extenso e muitas vezes doloroso. +1 por lembrar da reputação do IP. O cabra muitas vezes nem culpa tem da besteira cometida pelo "vizinho de hospedagem"

Comment: Muito interessante saber sobre reputação de IP e registros DNS, já passei horas tentando entender pq emails gerados em  em determinado servidor cloud, sempre eram classificados como spam, e não é um servidor barato como você citou, obrigado pelas informações.

Comment: Para ser ser mais preciso, dos 6 provedores de VPS que já usei, só em 1 deles tive esse problema dos envios serem imediatamente e irremediavelmente rejeitados por questão de reputação. Fazendo justiça: tem VPS de provedor "barato" (5 dólares por mês) que não tem problema nenhum também...

Answer (score 12):

São várias perguntas que você tem ai. Vou tentar responder da melhor forma possível.

Lembrando que dependendo do caso, o uso de serviços como o [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) é a melhor opção. O plano mais básico é gratuito e conforme a sua necessidade cresce, os planos se tornam mais *"parrudos"*.

1. **Qual formatação correta do cabeçalho do email `$headers .= "Content-type:text/html...` ?**
   $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
2. **É permitido o uso de CSS para estilizar?**
   Sim, porém este preferencialmente fica no html.
3. **É permitido o uso de imagem, qual a melhor maneira de usar?**
   Sim, é. Porém, é altamente recomendado o uso das tags `Alt` e não redimensione as imagens. Se precisa delas menores, use o photoshop.
4. **Existe um limite de destinatários?**
   Não, embora seja prudente separar os destinatários em vários grupos e sempre incluir seu e-mail de teste, para ter certeza de que o envio ocorreu bem.
5. **É melhor usar a função mail(), ou uma classe como PHPMailer para envio de e-mail autenticado?**
   Pessoalmente eu usaria o PHPMailer. Mas aí já caí pra opiniões, então nem vou tentar defender o método.

Adicionalmente, encontrei [um link contendo 20 dicas de melhores práticas na criação de e-mail marketing](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/20-email-design-best-practices-and-resources-for-beginners--net-7309). Acho cabível listar algumas:

- Não utilize imagens de fundo;
- Não ultrapasse 600px de largura - A maioria das pessoas que utilizam outlook por exemplo não abre seus e-mails. Por que enfiar uma barra de rolagem ao invés de mostrar toda a mensagem?
- [Teste sua aplicação](https://litmus.com/) para saber se os e-mails estão sendo enviados para todos os provedores;
- [Teste sua aplicação](http://caniuse.com/) em diversos navegadores.

Boa sorte.