# E-mail marketing, teórico

Tags: envio-de-email

Quero lembrar que esta pergunta não é uma pergunta de opinião, mas sim baseada em experiência.

Esta pergunta é apenas para ter uma ideia de como criar um E-mail marketing, perguntas mais detalhadas e específicas serão colocadas em tópicos diferentes.

Não quero que vocês desenvolvam nenhum sistema, apenas mostre a maneira lógica e teórica dos pré requisitos de um servidor de E-mail Marketing.

Por isto tenho uma série de perguntas.

- Eu somente preciso mandar E-mails para vários contatos em um banco de dados?
- Preciso colocar algum botão para a pessoa parar de receber E-mails?
- É possível ver quantas pessoas abriram o E-mail?
- Como não ser considerado um spam? É inevitável uma hora virar spam?
- Quais são as boas praticas e cuidados que devo ter em mente antes de programa-lo para não ser considerado um spam e não entrar na blacklist?
- O que mais é preciso para criar um E-mail Marketing?

Já tenho um conhecimento de como enviar E-mails via código, quero deixar claro que o que eu quero é a teoria para que eu possa programar. Acredito que a linguagem não é necessária vocês saberem porém se tiverem a curiosidade de saber eu vou fazer em PHP.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Primeiro, um pouco de teoria

Antes de mais nada, é importante deixar claro que *por princípio* qualquer comunicação em massa por email tem um grande potencial de ser considerada SPAM por qualquer filtro decente. Simplesmente porque ela tem características básicas de SPAM, tais como: grande número de destinatários, palavras/frases reconhecidamente utilizadas em mensagens indesejadas e/ou inseguras ("compre", "revalide", "urgente", etc).

Do ponto de vista de quem envia tais mensagens, é apenas "marketing" legítimo. Mas do ponto de vista de quem recebe, pode ser algo muito chato quando é repetitivo, inoportuno e, principalmente, não solicitado (isto é, nem sempre é um [lovely SPAM, wonderful SPAM!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kjdrl6qjwY) - a dita origem do termo). É claro que há aqueles clientes que desejam receber emails com notificações das mais diversas (isto é, estão interessados no seu marketing, mesmo que frequente e repetitivo - gosto é gosto!). Mas o papel dos filtros é diferenciar os emails desejados dos indesejados, e essa tarefa não é nada simples.

Nos primórdios do uso da Internet, muito dessa filtragem ficava a cargo do próprio usuário, porque (1) não havia tanta preocupação com o problema (ele talvez não fosse ainda muito evidente) e (2) não haviam soluções de software padronizadas nos servidores de email dos clientes. Era muito comum, por exemplo, se utilizar regras de email diratamente nos clientes de email (como o Outlook):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tais regras tinham a intenção de permitir organizar a caixa de entrada (automaticamente movendo emails com certos "padrões" para locais específicos), mas podiam ser utilizadas para mover automaticamente emails com padrões indesejados (aquele remetente, ou aquela palavra incluida no título, etc) para a lixeira. Essa abordagem tinha dois problemas. Primeiramente, ela requeria que o usuário soubesse o que estava fazendo e tivesse o trabalho de configurar as regras. Muitos usuários não sabem como fazer essa configuração e/ou não tinha o interesse (ou a paciência) para tal. Em segundo lugar, a "filtragem" acontecia no cliente de email, depois que a mensagem já tinha sido baixada. Assim, mesmo sendo eventualmente efetivo em separar as mensagens indesejadas, elas já haviam sido baixadas e consumido banda da comunicação do usuário (o que não era nada interessante quando a Internet era por linha discada e se pagava por pulsos durante a conexão).

Assim, a transição natural foi fazer com que o servidor de email do cliente recussasse as mensagens indesejadas imediatamente ao recebé-las por lá, sem a necessidade de baixá-las para o cliente. Isto é, essas mesmas regras (que incluem listas negras de remetentes, títulos com palavras específicas, etc) foram movidas para o servidor do cliente. Quem tem idade suficiente deve se lembrar da transição em que clientes de email locais como o Outlook ou o Incredimail deixaram de ser populares, sendo trocados pelo uso de opções chamadas de "Webmail" em que a mensagem era acessada e lida diretamente pelo navegador, sem baixar nada.

O problema das regras é que elas não são muito robustas. Lembro em uma empresa em que eu trabalhei que nós (programadores) brincávamos de testar o filtro de SPAM mandando mensagens uns aos outros com frases como:

> "Você sabia que na Ilha da Madeira a-
>
> bunda o ananás/abacaxi?"

(e o filtro barrava a mensagem por causa da palavra "abunda" separada por hífem). :)

É por isso que os filtros de SPAM tem sido melhorados com técnicas de estatística e aprendizagem de máquina. O princípio do aprendizado de máquina é aprender um modelo de previsão a partir de dados de exemplo (no caso desse problema, exemplos de mensagens *que são* SPAM e de mensagens *que não são* SPAM). Tendo-se esse modelo, pode-se prever a classificação para um novo dado. [Nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40135/explicar-o-algoritmo-svr/40149#40149) eu dei uma resposta mais didática sobre como funciona esse princípio (é com um algoritmo específico - existem muitos outros, mas a ideia geral é a mesma).

No caso de detecção de SPAM, é mais comum usar [entropia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropia_da_informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ou um modelo probabilístico para classificar as mensagens. Muito da evolução do filtro do Gmail (que eu acho que é o mais robusto hoje em dia) deve-se ao [Peter Norvig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Norvig), que além de trabalhar no Google é (ou foi, não sei ao certo) professor de Aprendizado de Máquina e de Processamento de Linguagem Natural em Stanford. Em [um exemplo muito (mas muito mesmo) didático de uma aula dele](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIEStL7riMo), ele demonstra esse princípio de como se pode "aprender" o padrão de um texto para então usá-lo em uma nova classificação futura.

Nesse caso, ele intencionalmente usa o gzip para servir como extrator de característica dos textos de exemplo. Nesse exemplo ele tem três textos usados para treinamento, um no idioma inglês, outro no idioma alemão e outro no idioma azerbajão:

> **Inglês (EN)**: *Hellow world! This is a file full of English words...*
>
> **Alemao (DE)**: *Hallo Welt! Dies ist eine Datei voll von deutschen Worte...*
>
> **Azerbajão (AZ)**: *Salam Dünya! Bu fayl Azerbaycan tam sözler...*

O "processo de aprendizado" é feito produzindo-se um modelo de cada um desses exemplos (isto é, um modelo para cada idioma). Então, usa-se o modelo para comparar um novo texto e descobrir a qual "classe" (no caso, idioma) ele provavelmente pertence. O texto novo (de idioma desconhecido) é esse:

> **(NEW)**: This is a new piece of text to be classified.

No exemplo, usa-se o gzip para descobrir a qual idioma o novo texto pertence com o comando:

```
(echo 'cat NEW EN | gzip | wc -c' EN; \
 echo 'cat NEW DE | gzip | wc -c' DE; \
 echo 'cat NEW AZ | gzip | wc -c' AZ) \
| sort -n | head -1
```

Esse comando basicamente faz o seguinte:

1. Concatena (cat) o novo texto (NEW) com cada texto de exemplos de um idioma (EN, DE e AZ), compacta (gzip) e conta o número de caracteres do resultado (wc).
2. Ordena o resultado pelo número de caracteres (sort)
3. E escolhe o menor (aquele com a compactação mais curta), exibindo a sigla do idioma do comando utilizado (EN, no caso).

A resposta vai ser aquela combinação com a melhor compactação (NEW + EN), porque ela decorre de como funciona o algoritmo de compactação. O algoritmo de compactação do gzip procura padrões de repetição no texto (no caso do inglês, o "is " é um desses padrões mais comuns) e trocando-os por valores representados com menos de um byte (por isso o arquivo fica menor, mais compactado). Quando o texto novo está no mesmo idioma do texto de exemplo, os mesmos padrões vão se repetir e por isso a compactação do texto novo concatenado ao texto do mesmo idioma tende a ser mais efetiva gerando menos caracteres na saída.

Note que esse é um exemplo didático. O filtro de SPAM do Gmail não usa o gzip, e sim um modelo probabilístico (muito provavelmente o [classificador Naive Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)) que descreve as probabilidades de cada palavra ocorrer em uma mensagem que é ou não SPAM. Esse modelo é continuamente ajustado pelas indicações dos próprios usuários (quando você marca uma mensagem como SPAM ou como não SPAM), então ele tende a ser cada vez mais efetivo.

### Tentando responder às suas perguntas efetivamente...

Sendo assim:

- **Eu somente preciso mandar E-mails para vários contatos em um banco de dados?**
  Sim, basta fazer isso. Mas idealmente, mande um email direto para cada destinatário. Se você mandar uma única mensagem para múltiplos destinatários você aumenta as chances da sua mensagem ser considerada SPAM porque esse é um forte indício utilizado principalmente por sistemas de filtro baseado em regras.
- **Preciso colocar algum botão para a pessoa parar de receber E-mails?**
  Filtros baseados em regras comumente usam esse critério (existência de link para solicitar a exclusão da lista de emails). Então, é bom você ter essa opção. De fato, essa opção é mandatória do ponto de vista da experiência do usuário (algo além do que você se preocupa atualmente) porque o usuário pode desejar parar de receber suas mensagens quando quiser. Se esse processo for fácil, o usuário realmente se sente no controle e não tem motivo pra ter algo contra a sua empresa/negócio.
- **É possível ver quantas pessoas abriram o E-mail?**
  Até onde eu sei, essa opção depende de uma nova mensagem enviada do servidor de email do destinatário ([RFC 2298](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2298.txt)) no momento em que a mensagem é recebida por ele (e não necessariamente aberta/lida pelo usuário). A ideia é fornecer um feedback sobre o sucesso da entrega, *mas sem ferir a privacidade do usuário*. Então, eu acredito que não há como saber exatamente quantas pessoas leram o email dessa forma. O que é comumente feito é solicitar que o usuário acesse um link específico, que então faz a contagem de acessos de retorno. Muitas "soluções" (pra não dizer SPAMMERS necessariamente... hehehe) usavam imagens externas (em outros sites) para tentar automatizar esse acesso de retorno, mas isso também tem sido bloqueado por motivos de segurança (spammers usavam essa técnica para validar emails de pessoas reais).
- **Como não ser considerado um spam? É inevitável uma hora virar spam?**
  Em princípio é só não fazer SPAM: isto é, não enviar emails indesejados ou propaganda exageradamente acintosa. Evite repetir a mesma mensagem (oferecer o mesmo produto em emails seguidos), trate os usuários individualmente e pelo nome correto que eles mesmos ofereceram em um cadastro (não use o "Olá senhor, dasilva.sauro!"), e solicite que os usuários verifiquem suas caixas de spam e marquem as mensagens como não-spam (para ajustar corretamente o algoritmo de filtragem para os emails da sua empresa).
- **Quais são as boas praticas e cuidados que devo ter em mente antes de programa-lo para não ser considerado um spam e não entrar na blacklist?**
  Essa pergunta é redundante com a anterior. E a resposta é: não faça SPAM. Seja honesto com o envio das mensagens e, principalmente, tenha sempre em mente que o usuário deve ter o controle sobre o envio delas, incluindo não somente se quer receber ou não, mas também (sempre que possível) o intervalo (diário, semanal, mensal, etc) e o horário (manhã, tarde, noite, etc) de envio para as mensagens.
- **O que mais é preciso para criar um E-mail Marketing?**
  Bom, a ferramenta de envio. Como você mesmo postou na seu segunda questão (que eu marquei como duplicada), um sistema de software que faça o acesso aos dados, monte a mensagem e a envie aos clientes é necessário. Já lhe foram sugeridas muitas opções que não requerem que você mesmo programe tudo do zero, e elas comumente são interessantes porque também facilitam ao oferecer boas práticas no uso de emails como abordagem de marketing.

P.S.: Em relação às melhores práticas que ajudam a evitar que uma mensagem seja caracterizada como SPAM, vale também a leitura [desta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14923/melhores-pr%C3%A1ticas-para-envios-de-emails-e-evitar-spam).

Answer (score 7):

Um bom sistema de e-mail marketing deve:

1) Permitir enviar e-mails apenas para usuários previamente cadastrados para tal finalidade.

2) Toda mensagem deve possuir um link para que o usuário remova seu cadastro do recebimento do mail marketing.

3) Sim é possível ter informações de quantas pessoas visualizaram o e-mail.

4) Spam só seria considerado se você enviasse mensagens para pessoas que não solicitaram previamente.

5) Para não entrar na blacklist você precisa ser uma fonte válida de envio de e-mails. Dependendo da frequência que enviar os e-mails, as aplicações também poderão entregar algumas mensagens direto na lixeira.

6) Antigamente as aplicações de e-mail não renderizam muito bem e-mails com css ou versões de html mais novas. Então muita gente formatava os e-mails com as tags html mais antigas e quando queria um design mais recuscado apelava para as imagens. Hoje você tem mais opções para criação dos e-mails.

O fluxo funciona da seguinte maneira: O usuário se cadastra pelo site para receber o mail marketing. Como ele autorizou o recebimento dos e-mails, você pode enviar seu mail marketing sem problemas. E caso ele não queira mais receber seus e-mails por algum motivo qualquer, ele tem o link para remover sua inscrição. Se você enviar os e-mails sem autorização, ai vira spam no contexto do mail marketing.

Comment: Seria possível explicar em mais detalhes alguns dos itens? O item 3, por exemplo. Como é possível isso, se esse controle está fora do escopo do servidor que envia os emails? O item 4 também não é necessariamente verdade (já que é bastante comum que mensagens desejadas caiam na caixa de SPAM indevidamente).

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu sei que é possível saber quem leu o e-mail, porque vários serviços de envio de e-mail fornecem dados a respeito, se eles conseguem é porque é possível. O MailChimp é um serviço muito utilizado que consegue essas informações. Não sei dizer como seria a implementação. Quanto ao item 4 eu quis dizer que no contexto do mail marketing isso é considerado spam. E não é qualquer tipo de e-mail, são e-mails promocionais por exemplo. Um e-mail de contato por exemplo não precisa de autorização prévia e nem por isso é considerado spam. Espero ter esclarecido melhor.

Comment: Justamente, a ideia é você *editar* a pergunta para incluir informações que descrevem o "como" (pra efetivamente responder à pergunta do AP). Você há de concordar que dizer "sim, é possível" não é lá de grande ajuda pra quem *precisa* ou *deseja* fazer isso (que não é só o AP, mas também outros leitores futuros).

Comment: @LuizVieira eu entendi sua colocação, acho muito interessante também ter detalhes a respeito como resolver essa questão. Porém eu entendo que a pergunta foi em sentido mais amplo. Agora se alguém interessar pode abrir um tópico mais específico sobre essa questão, tenho certeza que seria muito mais apropriado.

Comment: Ref. ao Item 3, basta marcar a opção de solicitar confirmação de leitura de email, muitos gerenciadores de email respondem essa confirmação de forma automática, e então implementar uma programação que receba as confirmações, claro que isso deixa uma margem de erro, pois pode ser configurado para não confirmar a leitura, mas já gera um numero "minimo" de leitores que abriram o email.